# Any idea how to setup pfsense WAN through a bridged network connection?

Tags: networking, pfsense

I've been trying to setup my rack server with pfsense to use an ethernet connection from a laptop that has a bridged wireless->ethernet connection - Yes I'm aware this will cause a drop in speed rather than direct ethernet from the ISP Router. However I don't have easy access to the router that is on the bottom floor of my house. The servers are on the 1st floor, therefore I was hoping to use the laptop bridge to an Ethernet and then use that as the WAN connection to the hub. Would this even be possible?

The only problem is there is no internet connection, I checked the Firewall Rules and there was nothing unordinary. Is it even possible to setup pfsense with a connection like this?

If you need more info - just ask.

Thanks,
- Jacob

Comment: This is most certainly possible. However, because the way wifi access points usually work, you will probably want to go with a routed solution. Wifi access points typically will deny traffic on MAC addresses that have no specifically performed authentication (which anything on your layer 2 bridge will not have). You could instead set up your wireless adapter to connect to your desired network, and then have your pfsense box use a different subnet for the wired connection with wifi as a configured gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the information, however I'm not completely confident on how todo this. I should probably add that I ain't using crossover ethernet for the bridged laptop to the router

Comment: If it's gigabit, there is no such thing as crossover anymore. It's autonegotiated. I'd like to describe with more specific details what I wrote above, but I'm not anywhere near a pfsense box at the moment.

Comment: I never knew it was dropped with Gigabit Ethernet, good to know! Also thank you for trying anyway, I think It might be an issue with the laptop I'm using to bridge though.

Comment: I just realised that the laptop I was using for the bridge doesn't have gigabit. going to try and use another desktop for the bridge